# How to do math operation in MultiIndex for columns Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to perform a simple math operation on a multindex columns pandas.
Take for example the multiindex as exemplified in the code below. In the first iteration,
The following variable should have the value as below

```
par_1=4
par_2=6
par_3=8
```

and the `BB` which is calculate as per the equation `(par_2+par_3+6) / par_1` should equal to `5`. However, in the code below, it is equal to `nan`

Following the calculation, I would like to extend the answer onto the existing `df`.

May I know what is the proper way of tackling this problem

```
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['all_cal'], ['a0_b0', 'a0_b1','a0_b3','a1_b0', 'a1_b1','a1_b3']],
                                     names=['subject', 'type'])
data=np.array([[4,6,8,4,5,6]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

for idx in [0,1]:
    par_1=df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_level_values(1)==f'a{str(idx)}_b0']
    par_2=df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_level_values(1)==f'a{str(idx)}_b1']
    par_3=df.iloc[0, df.columns.get_level_values(1)==f'a{str(idx)}_b3']
    BB=(par_2+par_3+6) / par_1
    df.loc [0, ('all_cal', f'{str(idx)}_new_info')] = (par_2+par_3+6) / par_1
    df.loc [0, ('all_cal', f'{str(idx)}_new_other')] = (par_2*2) / par_1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `loc` using index and columns names, particularly you must access using both column leves:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['all_cal'], ['a0_b0', 'a0_b1','a0_b3','a1_b0', 'a1_b1','a1_b3']],
                                     names=['subject', 'type'])
data=np.array([[4,6,8,4,5,6]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)

idx = 0
par_1 = df.loc[idx, ('all_cal', 'a0_b0')]
par_2 = df.loc[idx, ('all_cal', 'a0_b1')]
par_3 = df.loc[idx, ('all_cal', 'a0_b3')]
BB = (par_2 + par_3 + 6) / par_1
print(f"BB = {BB}")
df.loc[idx, ("all_cal", "new_info")] = (par_2 + par_3 + 6) / par_1
df.loc[idx, ("all_cal", "new_other")] = (par_2 * 2) / par_1
```

More detailed info [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)

PS: f-strings support numeric values, so you can avoid `str(idx)`, for example:

```py
print(f"f-strings support numbers like this: {idx}")
```

is a valid string.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can set up the MultiIndex differently:

```
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['a0', 'a1'], ['b0', 'b1','b3']],
                                     names=['subject', 'type'])
data=np.array([[4,6,8,4,5,6]])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
print(df)

subject a0       a1      
type    b0 b1 b3 b0 b1 b3
0        4  6  8  4  5  6
```

Then you can stack the `subject` level to do your calculations:

```
df = df.stack('subject')
df['new_info'] = (df['b1'] + df['b3'] + 6 ) / df['b0']
df['new_other'] = (2 * df['b1']**2) / df['b0']
print(df)
type       b0  b1  b3  new_info  new_other
  subject                                 
0 a0        4   6   8      5.00       18.0
  a1        4   5   6      4.25       12.5
```

...and then `unstack` them (and reorder things) if you want it to be "wide" again:

```
df = ( df.unstack('subject')
         .sort_index(axis=1, level='subject')
         .reorder_levels([1,0], axis=1)
     )
print(df)
subject a0                          a1                         
type    b0 b1 b3 new_info new_other b0 b1 b3 new_info new_other
0        4  6  8      5.0      18.0  4  5  6     4.25      12.5
```